# Cannot reconnect to Jupyter Lab kernel running on AWS (EC2) after disconnection

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-lab, tmux

I'm trying to train a neural network (Transformer) on an EC2 machine. It should take a long time so I want to run the training background and expect it will continue processing even after I disconnect my local PC from the EC2 instance.
I build a Jupyter Lab server on the instance and access it via local browser (Chrome).
Following some instructions on the web, I tried `nohup` and `tmux` to use background processing. I can run Jupyter and access it from my browser, but the problem is that the process doesn't look continuing when my browser is disconnected from the server.
What are the possible causes of the problem?

What I did are as below.

Login to the instance.

```
local $ ssh ec2
```

Build a tmux session.

```
ec2 $ tmux
```

Activate the pre-built python environment for pytorch projects.

```
tmux $ source activate pytorch
```

Start a jupyter server

```
tmux $ jupyter-lab --no-browser --port=8888 --ip=0.0.0.0
```

The logs are as follows.

> [I 2023-09-06 16:02:12.600 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully loaded.
> [I 2023-09-06 16:02:12.600 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /
> [I 2023-09-06 16:02:12.600 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 2.7.3 is running at:
> [I 2023-09-06 16:02:12.600 ServerApp] http://[hostname]:8888/lab
> [I 2023-09-06 16:02:12.600 ServerApp] http://[IP address]:8888/lab
> [I 2023-09-06 16:02:12.600 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
> [I 2023-09-06 16:02:12.624 ServerApp] Skipped non-installed server(s): bash-language-server, dockerfile-language-server-nodejs, javascript-typescript-langserver, jedi-language-server, julia-language-server, pyright, python-language-server, python-lsp-server, r-languageserver, sql-language-server, texlab, typescript-language-server, unified-language-server, vscode-css-languageserver-bin, vscode-html-languageserver-bin, vscode-json-languageserver-bin, yaml-language-server

Then access the Jupyter server from my local Google Chrome.
Create a notebook and run a simple code:

```
import time
for i in range(10000):
    print(f'Lap {i}', end='\r')
    time.sleep(3)
```

The output cell is updating the number every 3 seconds.

Logs in the tmux window:

> [W 2023-09-06 16:08:41.352 LabApp] Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs
> [I 2023-09-06 16:08:54.317 ServerApp] Creating new notebook in /data/projects
> [I 2023-09-06 16:09:00.075 ServerApp] Kernel started: c1d54e26-fc5a-4427-b63c-1294245d3eb6
> [I 2023-09-06 16:09:00.880 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel c1d54e26-fc5a-4427-b63c-1294245d3eb6.
> [I 2023-09-06 16:09:01.393 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel c1d54e26-fc5a-4427-b63c-1294245d3eb6.
> [I 2023-09-06 16:09:01.901 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel c1d54e26-fc5a-4427-b63c-1294245d3eb6.

Detach the tmux session and logout from EC2.

```
tmux $ [prefix] + d
ec2 $ logout
```

Close Chrome and disconnect my PC from the internet.
Several minutes later, Open Chrome and access Jupyter again.

Now the output cell is no longer updating. It shows 'Lap 49' this time, which may correspond to the auto-saving point shown in the log shown later.

The Kernel status is 'Idle'. I think this means the program is stopped even though it has not been running 30000 seconds.

Nothing changes even if I click 'Reconnect to kernel' in the menu.

Login to ec2 and attach the tmux session.

```
local $ ssh ec2
ec2 $ tmux attach
```

I can see the logs after disconnection:

> [I 2023-09-06 16:10:55.533 ServerApp] Saving file at /data/colab/projects/EJTrans_1.3M/Untitled.ipynb
> [I 2023-09-06 16:12:56.090 ServerApp] Saving file at /data/projects/Untitled.ipynb
> [I 2023-09-06 16:14:31.155 ServerApp] Starting buffering for c1d54e26-fc5a-4427-b63c-1294245d3eb6:508ea35d-bafd-417d-b6f1-d0e5c11909f0
> [W 2023-09-06 16:16:21.713 LabApp] Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs
> [I 2023-09-06 16:16:22.141 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel c1d54e26-fc5a-4427-b63c-1294245d3eb6.
> [I 2023-09-06 16:16:22.141 ServerApp] Discarding 37 buffered messages for c1d54e26-fc5a-4427-b63c-1294245d3eb6:508ea35d-bafd-417d-b6f1-d0e5c11909f0
> [I 2023-09-06 16:16:24.384 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel c1d54e26-fc5a-4427-b63c-1294245d3eb6.
> [I 2023-09-06 16:20:44.737 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel c1d54e26-fc5a-4427-b63c-1294245d3eb6.

I understand the log shows that my local PC is successfully connected to the running Jupyter serve, and Jupyter found the original kernel. (But the program is not running as mentioned above. )

When I run the cell again, the existing output ('Lap 49') disappears. And the cell number turns to [*] (means executing) but the kernel status stays as Idle and no new output appears.

My environments:

> SERVER
> AMI: Deep Learning AMI GPU TensorFlow 2.13 (Amazon Linux 2)
> 20230818
> Instance: p3.2xlarge (singel-GPU instance)
> Python environment: preset environment named 'pytorch' (provided in the AMI)
>
> CLIENT
> Mac OS Ventura 13.5.1
> Google Chrome Version 116.0.5845.140
> (Official Build) (x86_64)